# ExtJS How to count the total amount of a variable that was pulled by the script

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, modx

Basically I have website designed by someone else and I really dont understand ExtJS. I was wondering if anyone can help me.

Basically what I need to do is to put the total amount of "Names" pulled by the script and place it next to the "Name" column header.

I have tried the .getCount () and other various functions in the code but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me plz?

Thank you!

```
    MNWG.grid.Charities = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config,{
        id: 'mnwg-grid-charities'
        ,url: MNWG.connectorURL
        ,baseParams: { action: 'charities/getList' }
        ,fields: ['id','Created','Name','RegNo','Contact','Address','Postcode','Phone','Fax','Website','Email','Info','Notes','Tags',{name: 'FinancialAid',type:'boolean'}]
        ,paging: true
        ,remoteSort: true
        ,anchor: '97%'
        ,autoExpandColumn: 'name'
        ,columns: [{
            header: 'Name'

            ,dataIndex: 'Name'
            ,sortable: true
            ,width: 400
            ,editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }
        },{
            header: 'Contact'
            ,dataIndex: 'Contact'
            ,sortable: false
        },{
            header: 'Post code'
            ,dataIndex: 'Postcode'
            ,sortable: false
        },{
            header: 'Phone'
            ,dataIndex: 'Phone'
            ,sortable: false
            ,renderer: MNWG.renderers.phoneFax
        },{
            header: 'Website'
            ,dataIndex: 'Website'
            ,sortable: false
            ,renderer: MNWG.renderers.websiteLink
         },{
            header: 'Email'
            ,dataIndex: 'Email'
            ,sortable: false
            ,renderer: MNWG.renderers.emailLink
        }]
        ,tbar:[{
            xtype: 'textfield'
            ,id: 'mnwg-charities-search-filter'
            ,emptyText: 'Search...'
            ,listeners: {
                'change': {fn:this.search,scope:this}
                ,'render': {fn: function(cmp) {
                    new Ext.KeyMap(cmp.getEl(), {
                        key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER
                        ,fn: function() {
                            this.fireEvent('change',this);
                            this.blur();
                            return true;
                        }
                        ,scope: cmp
                    });
                },scope:this}
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'tbfill'
        },{
            xtype: 'button'
            ,text: 'Add new Charity'
            ,handler: {
                xtype: 'mnwg-window-createcharity'
                ,blankValues: true
            }
        }]

    });
    MNWG.grid.Charities.superclass.constructor.call(this,config)
};
Ext.extend(MNWG.grid.Charities,MODx.grid.Grid,{
    search: function(tf,nv,ov) {
        var s = this.getStore();
        s.baseParams.query = tf.getValue();
        this.getBottomToolbar().changePage(1);
        this.refresh();
    }
    ,getMenu: function(a,b,c) {
        var items = Array();

        // Check for a web url
        URL = a.menu.record.Website;
        if(URL != '' && URL != '/'){
            items.push({
                text: 'Visit Website'
                ,handler: this.visitWebsite
            });
        };

        // Check for an email address
        Email = a.menu.record.Email;
        if(Email!=''){
            items.push({
                text: 'Send Email'
                ,handler: this.sendEmail
            });
        };

        // Add update / delete buttons
        items.push({
            text: 'Update Details'
            ,handler: this.updateCharity
        },'-',{
            text: 'Remove Charity'
            ,handler: this.removeCharity
        });
        return items;
    }
    ,visitWebsite: function(a,b){
        var url = a.parentMenu.record.Website
        // Make sure URL is preceded by http://
        var patt= /^http/;
        if( ! patt.test(url)){
          url = 'http://'+url;
        };
        window.open(url);
    }
    ,sendEmail: function(a,b){
        var Email = a.parentMenu.record.Email
        window.open('mailto:'+Email);
    }
    ,removeCharity: function() {
        MODx.msg.confirm({
            title: 'Delete Charity'
            ,text: 'Are you sure you want to delete this charity? This cannot be reversed!'
            ,url: this.config.url
            ,params: {
                action: 'charities/remove'
                ,id: this.menu.record.id
            }
            ,listeners: {
                'success': {fn:this.refresh,scope:this}
                ,'failure': {fn: function(){ alert('fail'); },scope:this}
            }
        });
    }
    ,updateCharity: function(btn,e) {
        if (!this.updateCharityWindow) {
            this.updateCharityWindow = MODx.load({
                xtype: 'mnwg-window-updatecharity'
                ,record: this.menu.record
                ,listeners: {
                    'success': {fn:this.refresh,scope:this}
                }
            });
        }
        this.updateCharityWindow.setValues(this.menu.record);
        this.updateCharityWindow.show(e.target);
    }
});
Ext.reg('mnwg-grid-charities',MNWG.grid.Charities);



MNWG.renderers.websiteLink = function(val,a,record){
    // If no URL return blank
    if(val==''){return'';};

    // Make sure URL is preceded by http://
    var patt= /^http/;
    if( ! patt.test(val)){
      val = 'http://'+val;
    };

    // Create link
    return '<a href="'+val+'" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>';
};

MNWG.renderers.emailLink = function(val,a,record){
  // If no email return blank
  if( val=='' ){return '';};
  return '<a href="mailto:'+val+'">Send Email</a>';
};

MNWG.renderers.phoneFax = function(val,a,record){
    var html = '';
    if(record.data.Phone!=''){
        html+= '<img src="http://m.intertrustgroup.com/images/icon_phone.png" style="margin-right:.5em;">'+record.data.Phone+'<br />';
    };
    if(record.data.Fax!=''){    
        html+= '<img src="http://www.sliksvn.com/gfx/icon_fax.gif" style="margin-right:.5em;">'+record.data.Fax;
    };
    return html;    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to listen for the [datachanged](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-datachanged) event on the [store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) that retrieves the data from the server. Then on [datachanged](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-datachanged) get the column header and update it.

The following code snippet is an example of how you might achieve this by adding a listener to the [store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) applied to the grid.

*Updated code example*

**Change the Name column for simplicity**

```
{
    header: 'Name'
    ,id: 'mnwg-grid-charities-name'
    ,dataIndex: 'Name'
    ,sortable: true
    ,width: 400
    ,editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }
}
```

**Add the following code below this line** `MNWG.grid.Charities.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);`

```
MNWG.grid.Charities.getStore().addListener('datachanged', function(store) {
    Ext.ComponentManager.get('mnwg-grid-charities-name').setText('Name ' + store.count());
});
```

Comment: The listener goes below the top `fields: [`? if it does it doesnt work :(

Comment: No. It needs to be applied to the store that feeds your grid. This configuration isn't in your code so I can't provide an exact example I'm afraid. The grid config should have a property 'store' whatever that references is where you need to add the listener.

Comment: I updated the sample of my code to include all that is included in my file. Can you see there where there is a store? becasue i searched for the word "store" in the whole site code and couldnt find anything...

Comment: Ahhh it looks like your application is using MODExt which is an extension of Ext3 not 4. I'll have a look to see how to change my example

Comment: I don't have any experience with either products. Looking at the documentation though, that should be pretty close I think.